# Is React / Web or Python the way to create UIs for Raspberry Pi kiosks?

Tags: gui

I'm more of a full stack developer than anything so I've naturally just made chromium full screen on boot and hosted a web page for UI on raspberry kiosks.

My question is that if this approach is recommended? Are there any react native or electron approaches that are better? Does chromium even support JS that well to use React or another modern web library?

I'm also ignorant to Python, I'm sure there are more performant UI libraries but I would prefer to not learn another system when I already know web well enough.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I myself would select a desktop app, but as for 'the best', there is none.  However, I can say a few things:

- Raspbian (or whatever you decide on) works with Linux, specifically Debian.  Because of this, it is rather flexible, and you should be able to work something out.  For example, [I found this page on Electron](https://www.balena.io/blog/electronjs-the-ultimate-guide/)

  - Chromium is literally Chrome with some features removed.  It will work with basically anything.  It also updates just as frequently.

Hope that gets  you started.  Since it runs in Debian, there should be ample resources out there to get started.

Comment: yea agreed, there is no "best" approach but I wasn't sure if electron was the most commonly used platform for building raspberry pi desktop apps. Thanks for the link!